# What are the corresponding parameters of Requests "data" and "params" in urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib2

I have been successfully implementing python Requests module to send out POST requests to server with specified

> resp = requests.request("POST", url, proxies, data, headers, params, timeout)

However, for a certain reason, I now need to use python urllib2 module to query. For urllib2.urlopen's parameter "data," what I understand is that it helps to form the query string (which is the same as Requests "params"). requests.request's parameter "data," on the other hand, is used to fill the request body.

After searching and reading many posts, examples, and documentations, **I still have not been able to figure out what is the corresponding parameter of requests.request's "data" in urllib2**.

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks.

-Janton

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what it is called - it is a matter of passing it in at the right place.  For example in this example, the POST data is a dictionary (name can be anything).
The dictionary is urlencoded and the urlencoded name can again be anything but I've picked "postdata", which is the data that is POSTed

```
import urllib   # for the urlencode
import urllib2

searchdict = {'q' : 'urllib2'}
url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html'
postdata = urllib.urlencode(searchdict)

req = urllib2.Request(url, postdata)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print response.read()
print response.getcode()
```

If your POST data is plain text (not a Python type such as a dictionary) it can work without urllib.urlencode:

```
import urllib2

searchstring = 'q=urllib2'
url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html'

req = urllib2.Request(url, searchstring)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print response.read()
print response.getcode()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I am not saying that I am using both at the same time. I am trying to understand what to pass in to urllib2 as what I did to Requests.

Comment: I've replaced my answer based on your clarification.

Comment: The `data` parameter is called `data`... still nice answer +1